# getting social embed inside iframe renders element not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, bootstrap-4

I am using social embed for adding Instagram in the footer.

when I use the iframe given I get desired layout but it's not clickable

```
<iframe src="https://embedsocial.com/facebook_album/pro_hashtag/6dd7ae2bf3e784f6d8e6a05f854cdd8dba335e17" width="900px" height="1200px" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

but when i use this div its clickable but its not in iframe

```
<div class="embedsocial-hashtag" data-ref="6dd7ae2bf3e784f6d8e6a05f854cdd8dba335e17" style="width: 800px; height: 600px">
                        <script>(function (d, s, id) {
                            var js;
                            if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                                return;
                            }
                            js = d.createElement(s);
                            js.id = id;
                            js.src = "https://embedsocial.com/cdn/ht.js";
                            d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(js);
                        }(document, "script", "EmbedSocialHashtagScript"));</script>
```

how can i use this inside iframe and make it clickable

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try doing a classic IFrame without all the special stuff (marginheight="0" marginwidth="0") or you could use `<object data="URL" width="100" height="100"></object>`

Comment: As i have said, the posts inside the iframe are not clickable.

Comment: @SuhasKashyap did you try using the object tag? an example usage of the object tag is [this](https://feaded-boomball.glitch.me/)

Comment: yes! i had tried it already it doesnt work

Comment: alright then, that means you might just have to stick with the div because they probably used some type of code to block IFrame i mean the div code itself is genius anyways